# How to customise label and select option items in Vue3 using vuetify

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am trying to customize the label and select dropdown of a v-autocomplete in vue3 using vuetify. I want the label to contain the flag icon and dial_code of the selected option. Currently only the initial selectedCountry flag icon and dial_code are showing and when one selects a different country the label is blank. Also anyone with guidance on how one can search by country but only the dial_code reflects on the input.

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="4" md="3">
        <v-autocomplete
            variant="outlined"
            class="rounded"
            v-model="selectedCountry"
            :items="countryOptions"
            label="Country Code"
            item-title="name"
            item-value="dial_code"
      >
        <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
            <v-list-item
                v-bind="props"
            >
                <span>{{ item.raw.flag }} {{ item.raw.dial_code }}</span>
            </v-list-item>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:label>
            <span> {{ selectedCountry.flag }} {{selectedCountry.dial_code}} </span>
        </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
<script setup>
const countryOptions =
  [
    {
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AF",
      "dial_code": "+93"
    },
    {
      "name": "Åland Islands",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AX",
      "dial_code": "+358"
    },
    {
      "name": "Albania",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AL",
      "dial_code": "+355"
    },
    {
    "name": "Argentina",
    "flag": "",
    "code": "AR",
    "dial_code": "+54"
    },
    {
      "name": "Armenia",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AM",
      "dial_code": "+374"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aruba",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AW",
      "dial_code": "+297"
    },
    {
      "name": "Australia",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AU",
      "dial_code": "+61"
    },
    {
      "name": "Austria",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AT",
      "dial_code": "+43"
    },
    {
      "name": "Azerbaijan",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "AZ",
      "dial_code": "+994"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bahamas",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BS",
      "dial_code": "+1242"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bahrain",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BH",
      "dial_code": "+973"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bangladesh",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BD",
      "dial_code": "+880"
    },
    {
      "name": "Barbados",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BB",
      "dial_code": "+1246"
    },
    {
      "name": "Belarus",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BY",
      "dial_code": "+375"
    },
    {
      "name": "Belgium",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BE",
      "dial_code": "+32"
    },
    {
      "name": "Belize",
      "flag": "",
      "code": "BZ",
      "dial_code": "+501"
    }
  ]

const selectedCountry = countryOptions[0]

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `selectedCountry` reactive by putting it into a ref, so that the template can react to changes:

```
const selectedCountry = ref(countryOptions[0])
```

Also, since you use object data from `selectedCountry` in the label, the autocomplete has to return the whole object instead of only the number, which you get with the [`:return-object`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-return-object) property:

```html
<v-autocomplete
  ...
  return-object
>
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)